# MQTT brokers that provide User Interface and REST APIs for User/Topic configuration and management

Tags: mqtt

### Mosquitto MQTT

Some known facts whilst working with `mosquitto`:

- `mosquitto` is a Command-Line Interface based broker.
- Broker configuration is possible using `mosquitto.conf` file
- User Management is possible via a password-file and `mosquitto_passwd` CLI
- Every change either requires the Broker to be restarted (either using `systemd` or `system`) or the docker container needs to restarted OR using [`SIGUP` on the Process of Mosquitto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396710/adding-users-in-mqtt-broker#41397160)

#### Drawback

- If the Broker is deployed on cloud infrastructure, the administrator has to update the broker everytime and leading to downtimes (although small time intervals)
- If a User Interface is developed for the `mosquitto` broker, it would required the UI to access shell access which may require `root` access to perform broker restarts or calling the `kill -SIGHUP $pid_mosquitto` commands as well as other CLIs (dependent on the way the broker is installed)

### Requirements

- Is there a broker out there that lets users manage the broker's topic + user management plane either via RESTful APIs or via an UI?
- This is critical since it might be easier to handle the broker via such interfaces which `mosquitto` unfortunately does not provide

Comment: Just want to check if you considered point 2 in [the answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41397160/6650102) of using mosquitto-auth-plugin? Would that help somewhat or are there other configuration options that need to be changed as well?

Answer (score 1):

As @Aurora001 pointed out in the comments the solution to this is to use the mosquitto-auth-plugin (or write your own plugin using the mosquitto plugin API). While the original plugin has been archived there are active forks being worked on.

Extending the existing mosquitto docker container to build the plugin is not hard.

Many different brokers offer database backends to the Authentication/Authorisation systems, how you choose to update the database it up to you.